# wpf Datagrid :which Validation method is best for datagrid

Tags: wpf, validation, datagrid

I want to validate the datagrid cell namely Item column when the user input against database table itemMaster .My doubt is which method is best for me to validate the input ,ValidationRule or IDataErrorInfo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is 100% a duplicate. You could have found the answer to this yourself.

Use IDataErrorInfo because then you will be able to validate your input inside ViewModel where you also will be able to access another values/properties/data if needed for your validation.

Futhermore you will be able to swap ViewModels and so change the validation which you will not be able to achieve with ValidationRules easly.

Validation of ViewModel properties should be done in ViewModel. Its centralized and its also testable. It shouldnt not become a part of View except it has to for whatever reason.

You should use ValidationRules when you have binding between two control properties but in this scenario your validation belongs to the "View" anyways and stays inside the View part of MVVM.

Comment: dev hedgehog, iam not familiar with MVVM ,Iam using simple wpf application ,the view and viewModel is a new thing to me . Is it possible the calculations under a one setter eg;when qty change I want to calculate the amount=Qty * Rate ?

Comment: I dont want to sound rude or anything but "Is it possible the calculations under a one setter eg;when qty change I want to calculate the amount=Qty * Rate" - makes me feel like lost in space. You should read about MVVM first.